# Bootstrap 'container' shadows

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to give my page's container a shadow effect (starts dark on bottom and becomes white on top) BUT, only on the left and right side (imagine two vertical lines). But most of the tutorial found just 'shadow' the top or left/right, or bottom left/right. I really need to give a shadow effect to my website container, so any help will be great

Answer (score 3):

This trick might helpful

[BoxShadow](http://jsfiddle.net/afshinprofe/8YsAg/3/)

Answer (score 1):

try to use [css3 generator website](http://css3generator.com/) to generate shadow, maybe you are missing something or around your container are other elements with position absolute and high z-index. maybe you can do a printscreen?